# Jewish Mysticism/Kabbalah - Separation of souls from Hashem good, bad, or neither?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, christianity, zohar

This is an except from G.K. Chesterton's "Romance of Orthodoxy".  Chesterton was a  English writer, philosopher, lay theologian, and argues that Buddhism and the Theosophical concept of one god that detests separation and really wants all souls to unit.  Chesterton asserts that Christianity says that man should learn to love another and G-d rejoices in this division.  Is this what Kabbalah/Zohar teaches?  My understanding is that Hashem's divine sparks are separated and it is up to man to uncover those divine sparks.  Judaism does affirm the clear division of souls, and that Hashem separated us so that we may learn to love Him, correct?  It seems like Chesterton, to me at least, is affirming a concept already present in Jewish mystical thought, if I understand correctly.  I am just trying to share this idea with others and see if I am interpreting correct.  Thank you

> A short time ago Mrs. Besant, in an interesting essay, announced that
> there was only one religion in the world, that all faiths were only
> versions or perversions of it, and that she was quite prepared to say
> what it was. According to Mrs. Besant this universal Church is simply
> the universal self. It is the doctrine that we are really all one
> person; that there are no real walls of individuality between man and
> man. If I may put it so, she does not tell us to love our neighbours;
> she tells us to be our neighbours. That is Mrs. Besant's thoughtful
> and suggestive description of the religion in which all men must find
> themselves in agreement. And I never heard of any suggestion in my
> life with which I more violently disagree. **I want to love my neighbour
> not because he is I, but precisely because he is not I**. I want to
> adore the world, not as one likes a looking-glass, because it is one's
> self, but as one loves a woman, because she is entirely different. If
> souls are separate love is possible. If souls are united love is
> obviously impossible. A man may be said loosely to love himself, but
> he can hardly fall in love with himself, or, if he does, it must be a
> monotonous courtship. If the world is full of real selves, they can be
> really unselfish selves. But upon **Mrs. Besant's principle the whole
> cosmos is only one enormously selfish person**.
>
> It is just here that Buddhism is on the side of modern pantheism and
> immanence. And it is just here that Christianity is on the side of
> humanity and liberty and love. **Love desires personality; therefore
> love desires division. It is the instinct of Christianity to be glad
> that God has broken the universe into little pieces, because they are
> living pieces. It is her instinct to say "little children love one
> another" rather than to tell one large person to love himself.** This is
> the intellectual abyss between Buddhism and Christianity; that for the
> Buddhist or Theosophist personality is the fall of man, for the
> Christian it is the purpose of God, the whole point of his cosmic
> idea.

> The world-soul of the Theosophists asks man to love it only in order
> that man may throw himself into it. But the divine centre of
> Christianity actually threw man out of it in order that he might love
> it. **The oriental deity is like a giant who should have lost his leg or
> hand and be always seeking to find it; but the Christian power is like
> some giant who in a strange generosity should cut off his right hand,
> so that it might of its own accord shake hands with him.**... **No
> other philosophy makes God actually rejoice in the separation of the
> universe into living souls.**

Comment: Generally speaking, when you talk about inspiration, this is often a reference to an escape from the bounds of man. E.g. we can talk about Divinely inspired intellectual inspiration, in this regard we mean access to infinite understanding. Or we can talk about Divine love, which is a love greater than that which man can find in his own heart. To the extent that man *is* Divine, for he was made in His image, man finds all others within his own heart.